# Can't use global variable inside tree.enumNodeFragments() delegate

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I trying to save old materials of elements by fragId but can't do this because inside of  tree.enumNodeFragments() document nor window isn't accessible.

```
    highlight(externalId, color, dict) {
    let viewer = this.viewer;
    var dbId = dict[externalId];


    let myMaterial = this.createMaterial(color);

    // used to rescale and remove the z-fighting
    let scaleRatio = 1.005; // this was determined as optimal through visual inspection

    var tree = NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().instanceTree;

    document.oldMaterials = {};


    tree.enumNodeFragments(dbId,
        function(fragId) {
         document.oldMaterials[fragId] = viewer.model.getFragmentList().getMaterial(fragId);

            viewer.model.getFragmentList().setMaterial(fragId, myMaterial);


            /* important technique if you want to remove z-fighting */
            let fragProxy = viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(viewer.model, fragId);
            fragProxy.scale = new THREE.Vector3(scaleRatio, scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
            fragProxy.updateAnimTransform();
        },
        true);

    viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `document` and `window` should be available in the scope of the callback function, however it's not a good practice. Try defining the map of old materials inside the scope of the `highlight` function:

```
function highlight(externalId, color, dict) {
    const viewer = this.viewer;
    const dbId = dict[externalId];
    const myMaterial = this.createMaterial(color);
    // used to rescale and remove the z-fighting
    const scaleRatio = 1.005; // this was determined as optimal through visual inspection
    const tree = NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().instanceTree;
    const oldMaterials = {};

    tree.enumNodeFragments(dbId, function(fragId) {
        oldMaterials[fragId] = viewer.model.getFragmentList().getMaterial(fragId);
        viewer.model.getFragmentList().setMaterial(fragId, myMaterial);
        /* important technique if you want to remove z-fighting */
        const fragProxy = viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(viewer.model, fragId);
        fragProxy.scale = new THREE.Vector3(scaleRatio, scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
        fragProxy.updateAnimTransform();
    },
    true);

    viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
}
```

Comment: I try this sometimes ago. After call tree.enumNodeFragments oldMaterials is empty. viewer.model.getFragmentList().getMaterial(fragId) isn't empty.

Comment: I call console.log(document.oldMaterials) or console.log(window.oldMaterials) after  tree.enumNodeFragments and in console I see {} (empty dictionary).

Comment: As I mentioned, referring to a global variable (and especially `document`), is not a good practice and could cause different issues. Try using the local `oldMaterials` const instead, and make sure that the callback function inside `enumNodeFragments` actually executes.

Comment: How I can make sure that the callback function inside enumNodeFragments actually executes?

Comment: What I meant was: confirm that the callback function is actually executed, for example by putting a `console.log` or `debugger` statement in it.